# Desplegar ANGULAR4 en servidor APACHE

Tags: php, angular, apache, servidor

Quiero desplegar una app **Angular4** en un servidor **Apache**. Tras investigar un buen rato, ésto es lo que he hecho hasta ahora:

1. **ng build --prod**   ->   Se ha creado una carpeta **dist** en mi aplicación.
2. He copiado (debería cortarla?) y pegado esta carpeta **dist** en la carpeta HTDOCS de XAMPP.
3. Entro en mi aplicación a traves de:

> localhost/dist/mi_aplicacion

.

Me sale el siguiente error:

> Ha fallado la carga del  con origen
>   "http://localhost/assets/jquery.min.js". webapp:12:1 Ha fallado la
>   carga del  con origen
>   "http://localhost/runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js". webapp:24:1 Ha
>   fallado la carga del  con origen
>   "http://localhost/polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js". webapp:24:1 Ha
>   fallado la carga del  con origen
>   "http://localhost/main.3c75e630a45dcb9eae9c.js".

¿Puede alguién guiarme un poco?

Comment: La carpeta dist debe moverla a /var/www/ y debes entrar en http://localhost/dist

Comment: No encuentro esa carpeta, estoy con XAMPP, y por lo que tengo entendido éste no tiene esa carpeta.

Answer (score 0):

Al desplegar la aplicación a un entorno de producción, podemos indicarle cual va a ser la URL base.

```
ng build --prod  --bh http://localhost/dist/mi_aplicacion
```

También puedes editar este archivo, el que indica cual es la base URL, con un editor de texto. Es el archivo index.html dentro de la raíz de la carpeta /dist

Otra opción es que copies los archivos que hay dentro de la carpeta /dist y lo pegues dentro de la carpeta HTDOCS  del XAMPP

Comment: ng build --prod --bh daba error, por lo que he hecho (no sé si he estado en lo correcto): ng build --base-href http://localhost/dist/mi_aplicacion. Luego he movido la carpeta DIST a HTDOCS. Al ir a la URL ocurre lo mismo, encuentra el archivo pero no muestra nada y da los mismos fallos.